# Proof of the Stable Matching Problem

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques, matching

Looking at the document *Fundamentals of Computing Series*, [The Stable Marriage Problem](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15251-f10/Site/Materials/Lectures/Lecture21/lecture21.pdf).

Theorem 1.2.3 - page 12:

> In a man-optimal version of stable matching, each woman has worst
>   partner that she can have in any stable matching.

Proof:

> Suppose not. Let $M_0$ be the man-optimal stable matching, and
>   suppose there is a stable matching $M’$ and a woman $w$ such
>   that $w$ prefers $m = p_{M_0}(w)$ to $m' = p_{M'}(w)$ . But
>   then $(m,w)$ blocks $M'$ unless $m$ prefers $p_{M'}(m)$ to 
>   $w = p_{M_0}(m)$, in contradiction of the fact that $m$ has no
>   stable partner better than his partner in $M_0$.

I'm having trouble visualizing the definition of the problem and the proof (what is the contradiction?).

First, what is the question implying?  From what I read and the fact that in most stable matching examples, all the women do not end up with the completely last person on their list ... So I'm a bit confused.

In the proof, here is what I am getting: in $M'$ we suppose $w$ prefers $m$ to $m'$.  But then if there is a stable matching containing $(m,w)$ this would leave $w$ with her worst partner and that is a contradiction.  Is this correct?

In addition, if $m$ did prefer $w'$ it would contradict that it is not his first pick ?

I'm new to computer science concepts so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is not that every woman ends with the last man on her list. Rather, consider *all* stable matchings, and all partners of some woman $w$ in these stable matchings. Among them, pick the worst one (according to her view) $m$. Then in the man-optimal matching, $w$ is matched to $m$.

Now that you understand what they're trying to prove, read the proof again. (It couldn't have made sense before, because the claim as you stated it just isn't true.)

Comment: ok I see now, that you. In this case, is it true that with the G-S algorithm, there can only be 2 sets of stable matching (with stable matching set 1 with man-optimal and the other one coming from woman-optimal)?

Comment: Definitely not. There could be exponentially many stable matchings.

Comment: You can check the book by Gusfield and Irving, The Stable Marriage Problem: Structure and Algorithms, or the lecture notes by Knuth.

Comment: does it depend on the order of men picked to propose?

Comment: Any implementation of the Gale-Shapley algorithm produces a single stable matching. However, there are lots more stable matchings out there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice [lecture video on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1leqkpDaRw) which describes all properties. I recommend you to watch is if you are new to the concept.